# Vue3 and Vite build subfolder for assets

Tags: vuejs3, vite

I would like to set my `vite.config.js` to build assets split into subfolders for js, CSS, and images.

Basically, I would like to have a build like this:

```
dist/
   - index.html
   - assets/
           - images/
           - css/ 
           - js/
```

How should I change the config?

Answer (score 1):

A config like this should do it.

```
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        // plugins...
    ],
    build: {
        rollupOptions: {
            input: {
                'js/index': 'pathto/yourjsfile.js',
                // and other input files...
            },
            output: {
                dir: 'dist',
                assetFileNames: (assetInfo) => { // more info https://rollupjs.org/configuration-options/#output-assetfilenames
                    // for testing if image
                    var imageReg = /[\/.](gif|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png)$/i;
                    
                    if (imageReg.test(assetInfo.name)) {
                        return 'assets/images/[name]-[hash][extname]';
                    } else if (assetInfo.name.endsWith('.css')) {
                        return 'assets/css/[name]-[hash][extname]';
                    } else else if (assetInfo.name.endsWith('.ttf') || assetInfo.name.endsWith('.eot') || assetInfo.name.endsWith('.woff') || assetInfo.name.endsWith('.woff2')) {
                        return 'assets/fonts/[name]-[hash][extname]';
                    } else {
                        return 'assets/[name]-[hash][extname]'
                    }
                },
            },
        },
        //outDir: 'dist',
    },
    server: {
        hmr: {
            protocol: 'ws'
        }
    }
})
```